# Python getters and setters method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to assign a third key for a new function `set_sigma_s` just like I did for the one `set_sigma_s` with two keys. Everything is the same but this time I am getting a

> TypeError: set_sigma_s() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given).

My code is below:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
class Material():
    def __init__(self, num_mat, num_groups):
        self.num_mat = num_mat                
        self.num_groups = num_groups            
        self.map = {} 

    def sigma_t(self, key1, key2):
            return self.map[key1, key2]

    def set_sigma_t(self, key1, key2, v):
            self.map[key1, key2] = v

    def sigma_s(self, key1, key2, key3):
            return self.map[key1, key2, key3]

    def set_sigma_s(self, key1, key2, key3, v):
            self.map[key1, key2, key3] = v

    def display(self):
            table = [["Number of Materials:", len(num_mat), None],["Number of Groups:", len(num_groups), None],
                     ["Material",num_mat[0], None],["gp",num_groups[0],num_groups[1]],["Total",mat.sigma_t(0, 0), mat.sigma_t(0, 1)],
                     ["0<-gp",mat.set_sigma_s(0, 0, 0),mat.set_sigma_s(0, 0, 1)],["1<-gp",mat.set_sigma_s(0, 1, 0),mat.set_sigma_s(0, 1, 1)]]
            return tabulate(table, tablefmt="rst")

num_mat = [0,1,2]
num_groups = [0,1]

mat = Material(num_mat, num_groups)
mat = Material(3,2)
mat.set_sigma_t(0, 0, 1.0)
mat.set_sigma_t(0, 1, 2.0)

mat.set_sigma_s(0, 0, 0, 1.0)
mat.set_sigma_s(0, 0, 1, 2.0)
mat.set_sigma_s(0, 1, 0, 3.0)
mat.set_sigma_s(0, 1, 1, 4.0)

print mat.sigma_t(0, 0)
print mat.display()
```

Comment: Please post the complete exception with traceback, not just the message. Otherwise, we can't know which line of code the problem happens on—we can _guess_, but we may not be guessing right, so we may not be solving your actual error.

Comment: If you were to show us the full stack trace, it'd point at the offending line

Comment: @TanveerAlam: Your changes are either introducing indentation errors that aren't present in the original code, hiding indentation errors that might be relevant to the problem, or both. The latest version has a mix of tabs and spaces—was that true in the OP's code?

Comment: Well I think the OP might not be familiar with SO's formatting patterns. But if I might have changed the question in different indentation level then I request  OP to please edit it again to match the indentation level he is having.

Comment: Okay, it's just a type error. It should be self.sigma_s(.....) instead of mat.set_sigma_s(.....) to get the value. Thanks everyone.

Comment: no, it should be `self.sigma_s(...)`

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of `display` you repeatedly have calls like `mat.set_sigma_s(0, 0, 1)`, but your `set_sigma_s` takes 4 arguments apart from `self`.

Additionally `mat` refers to the one `mat` variable you have, not the current object being operated on.  Instead you should be using `self` inside the method to mean "whichever object `display` was called on.

I'm further confused by what you want there because you have the call inside of the creation of a list, but `set_sigma_s` doesn't return anything.  Maybe instead you meant to call `self.sigma_s(0, 0, 0)` to read the value?

Comment: Worse, `mat` _does_ exist in that context, as a global variable, so instead of getting an error he silently gets the wrong thing (every material prints the same global `mat` object's stuff instead of its own stuff…).